# Type refinements in Scala but without using refined

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, refinement-type, refined

I am trying to create a HexString type based on String which should fulfill the condition "that it contains only hexadecimal digits" and I would like to have the compiler typecheck it for me, if possible.

One obvious solution would be to use [refined](https://github.com/fthomas/refined) and write something like this:

```scala
type HexString = String Refined MatchesRegex[W.`"""^(([0-9a-f]+)|([0-9A-F]+))$"""`.T]
refineMV[MatchesRegex[W.`"""^(([0-9a-f]+)|([0-9A-F]+))$"""`.T]]("AF0")
```

Now, I have nothing against refined, it's that I find it a bit of an overkill for what I am trying to do (and have no idea whether I am going to use it in other places at all) and I am reluctant to import a library which I am not sure will be used more than once or twice overall and brings syntax that might look like magic (if not to me, to other devs on the team).

The best I can write with pure Scala code, on the other hand, is a value class with smart constructors, which is all fine and feels lightweight to me, except that I cannot do compile-time type checking. It looks something like this at the moment:

```scala
final case class HexString private (str: String) extends AnyVal {
  // ...
}

object HexString {
  def fromStringLiteral(literal: String): HexString = {
    def isValid(str: String): Boolean = "\\p{XDigit}+".r.pattern.matcher(str).matches

    if (isValid(literal)) HexString(literal)
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a valid hexadecimal string")
  }
}
```

For most of the codebase, runtime checking is enough as it is; however, I might need to have compile-time checking at some point and there seems to be no way of achieving it short of using refined.

If I can keep the code as localized and as understandable as possible, without introducing much magic, would it be possible to use a macro and instruct the compiler to test the RHS of assignment against a regex and depending on whether it matches or not, it would create an instance of HexString or spit a compiler error?

```scala
val ex1: HexString = "AF0" // HexString("AF0")
val ex2: HexString = "Hello World" // doesn't compile
```

*Other than ADT traversal and transformation programs I've written using Scala meta, I don't really have experience with Scala macros.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `fromStringLiteral` to work at compile time you can make it a [macro](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html) (see sbt [settings](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Macro-Projects.html))

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def fromStringLiteral(literal: String): HexString = macro fromStringLiteralImpl

def fromStringLiteralImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(literal: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._

  val literalStr = literal match {
    case q"${s: String}" => s
    case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"$literal is not a string literal")
  }

  if (isValid(literalStr)) q"HexString($literal)"
  else c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"$literalStr is not a valid hexadecimal string")
}
```

Then

```
val ex1: HexString = HexString.fromStringLiteral("AF0") // HexString("AF0")
//val ex2: HexString = HexString.fromStringLiteral("Hello World") // doesn't compile
```

If you want this to work like

```
import HexString._
val ex1: HexString = "AF0" // HexString("AF0")
//val ex2: HexString = "Hello World" // doesn't compile
```

then additionally you can make `fromStringLiteral` an implicit conversion

```
implicit def fromStringLiteral(literal: String): HexString = macro fromStringLiteralImpl
```

Comment: it seems like this is what I want. One slight complication I would have is that the project in question uses Gradle instead of sbt and am not sure whether the settings link you provided is going to be of help... Hmmm, or should I just create a simple library and use sbt there?

Comment: @StefanPavikevik you should set up your building tool (for example gradle). You can use sbt link as an exampe of settings (you should create two projects).

Comment: @StefanPavikevik Did you manage to set up Gradle to work with macros?

Comment: I did manage somehow by setting up a separate project in a separate directory with its own build.gradle file. I then added it as a dependency in the main project `implementation project("macros")`

Thanks a lot for all the assistance!